# Как я могу получить идентификатор из URL-адреса в React и передать его на сервер?(Next js ) Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookie, jwt, nextjs

У меня есть компонент Settings.tsx настройками для изменения данных, и у каждого из этих профилей есть маршрут profile/[id]. В настоящее время мой код проверяет, авторизован ли пользователь с помощью файлов cookie, и отправляет его на серверную часть. По сути, любой авторизованный пользователь может изменить чужие данные. Я хочу взять идентификатор из этого маршрута и отправить его на сервер для обработки. Как я могу этого добиться? Файлы cookie шифруются с помощью JWT.

Вот мой код:

```
import styles from './Setting.module.css';
import ProfileSvg from "../../../public/profile.svg";
import useAuthCheck from "../../../hook/UseAuth";

const Setting =() => {
    const isAuthorized = useAuthCheck();
    console.log(isAuthorized)


    return (

        <div className={styles.container}>
            {isAuthorized ? (
                <div className={styles.nav_menu}>
                    <a>Мои посты</a>
                    <a>Настройки</a>
                </div>

            ):(
                <div className={styles.nav_menu}>
                    <a>Блог</a>

                </div>

            )}

            {isAuthorized ? (
                <>

                <h2>Настройки</h2>
                <div className={styles.hierarchy}>
                    <h4></h4>
                    <span>Главная<span><span className={styles.para}>></span>Настройки</span></span>

                </div>


                <div className={styles.user_profile}>

                    <div className={styles.container_settings}>

                        <h4>Имя</h4>
                        <input className={styles.input} type="text" name="name" value={isAuthorized.name}/>
                        <div className={styles.container_images}>
                            <div className={styles.img}>
                                <img  className={styles.img_avatar} src={"http://localhost:5000/" + isAuthorized.photo} alt="Profile" width={50} height={50} />



                            </div>

                            <div className={styles.name}>
                                <h4>Сменить аватарку</h4>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className={styles.email}>

                            <div className={styles.password}>
                                <h4>Сменить пароль</h4>
                                <input className={styles.input} type="text" name="password"/>
                            </div>
                        <div className={styles.button_name}>
                            <a>Сохранить</a>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    </div>



                </div>


                </>


            ):(

                <div className={styles.container_settings}>

                    <h1>Пройдите пожалуйста авторизацию</h1>
                </div>

            )}

        </div>




    )
}

export default Setting;
```

Comment: Если id - это идентификатор пользователя в profile/[id], то проще всего это переделать) Сделать просто страницу profile, чтобы нельзя было перейти в редактирование профиля другого пользователя

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил свою проблему с помощью useRouter()

```
const router = useRouter();
const { id } = router.query;
console.log(id);
```